# Update CRM Lookup Field from C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am attempting to develop an application to allow updates to our CRM database via a gridview.

Everything I have was working till attempting to update a lookup field.

The following is working C# code:

```
_service = GlobalFunctions.GetServiceAccount();
GlobalFunctions.User u = (GlobalFunctions.User)Session["UserInfo"];

Entity aspiration = new Entity("tog_aspiration");
aspiration.Id = new Guid(inputGridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
aspiration["tog_nofollrl"] = Int32.Parse(tog_nofollrl);
_service.Update(aspiration);
```

Now when attempting to add the lookup field to the update it gives me an error.

```
_service = GlobalFunctions.GetServiceAccount();
GlobalFunctions.User u = (GlobalFunctions.User)Session["UserInfo"];

Entity aspiration = new Entity("tog_aspiration");
aspiration.Id = new Guid(inputGridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
aspiration["tog_nofollrl"] = Int32.Parse(tog_nofollrl);
aspiration["tog_techidname"] = new EntityReference("equipment", new Guid(ddlVet.SelectedValue));
_service.Update(aspiration);
```

Here is the error

```
Incorrect attribute value type System.String 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Incorrect attribute value type System.String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure, is the lookup field called tog_techidname or just tog_techid? Every lookup has an associated name field, which is the lookup name + "name", but you can't update it directly. It is enough to just update the id with the EntityReference.

Try with

```
aspiration["tog_techid"] = new EntityReference("equipment", new Guid(ddlVet.SelectedValue));
```

Comment: i just tried that and it failed with the same error. Im not 100% sure that "equipment" is right. What should the parameters of the EntityReference() be?

Comment: also "tog_techidname" is the column name in the database. i looked in the equipment view in the database and it contains equipmentid and name. it does not contain equipmentidname.

Comment: What's the name of the field in the CRM entity? EntityReference should be a pair of the Entity's LogicalName and a Guid, nothing else.

Comment: well the entity pulls in the correct GUID as well as the correct entity but now it isn't pulling in the `name` field.